# Flutter application not running

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to run flutter app on my device but it is not running. It just get stuck here

```
Launching lib\main.dart on ANE LX1 in debug mode...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
```

It is running fine on emulator or any other device. I have also enabled usb debugging.
Here is flutter doctor output

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.535], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] VS Code (version 1.41.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

Comment: it takes time to run the first time.

Answer (score 0):

change minSdkVersion to your device API in android/app/build.gradle